# Matrices- Word problem

Tags: matrices

Three card players make an agreement which is that after each game the loser needs to double the money that the other two players have laid on the table.  Each player lays at the beginning of the game a certain amount of money on the table and does nothing to it than what the agreement allows. After three rounds, which is lost by each of one of them, each player has laid exact the same amount on the table: a euros. How much money did each player have at the beginning of the game?

I tried to solve it with a system of equations as follows:

$$x = \frac{y+z}{2}$$
$$y = \frac{x+z}{2}$$
$$z = \frac{x+y}{2}$$

I know that I didn't pay attention to the fact that each player at the end has exact the same amount. But I don't know how write it down.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Suppose the players start by putting $x,y,z$ on the table and the first players loses. So he has to give $y$ to the second player and $z$ to the third player. Does that come out of $x$ or is he putting additional money on the table?

Comment: No, he isn't putting any additional money. And thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Initially the 1st, 2nd, 3rd player put $x,y,z$ on the table.

After the first round they have: $x-y-z,2y,2z$.

After the 2nd round they have: $2x-2y-2z,-x+3y-z,4z$

After the 3rd round they have: $4x-4y-4z,-2x+6y-2z,-x-y+7z$

These amounts are equal. Equating the 1st and 2nd gives $3x=5y+z$. Equating the 2nd and 3rd gives $7y=x+9z$. Hence $21y-27z=5y+z$, so $4y=7z$. So we have $y=7k,z=4k$ and hence $x=13k$.

Check: $13,7,4\to 2,14,8\to 4,4,16\to 8,8,8$.